# How to add the jfxtras agenda from scene builder?

Tags: javafx, jfxtras

Is that any way add the jfxtras agenda from scene builder? I am getting crazy trying to work with fxml file, Any code example or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

A likely problem is that SceneBuilder does not support dependencies, so you need to use the "all" version of JFXtras. After that it is just a matter of including that jar as a library.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will try it.